# How to convert a node.js server to MVC?

Tags: javascript, web-services, model-view-controller, node.js

I have a Node.js server and the code is getting kind of big and messy. Am I correct to assume that converting this to MVC will make it more manageable? How do I go about doing that? Are there any tools that can help me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [RailwayJS](http://railwayjs.com/). It's the Node.JS MVC framework based on [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com).

Comment: I already tried that before. It can generate new pages, but how can it be used to convert a web server?